# Android listen for backbutton & Menu button longclick together

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I am overriding the behaviour of backbutton & Menu button Single Click & long click together.How can i detect this in Android code

Screen shot is taken from Nexus phone version (6.0)

After Clicking on Back & Menu button together,I got this Log

```
 Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=69741827, downTime=69741172, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 } I
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the events of the back and recent apps key when the app is not opened? If you so you can use the AccessblityService to listen to this events. If you just want to override the back button inside of the activity, you can just use onBackPressed()

Comment: I have opened one app.I'm locking that app.If user clicks on  any button it should not open other screen except opened app.I have done that for back,home,recent apps button click ,But if itry to press "back & recent apps " key together It is going to Home screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code of overriding `Back Button`!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //This Override Method Alters System Back Button's default function

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is only for back button.I need for both "back & recent apps" button click together.